# Overlapping a div with an image using z-index

Tags: html, css

A CSS animation is continuously playing behind an image. When the image is not loaded it will display, but when loaded the image will overlap the animation. I'm using z-index to achieve this, but it's not working.

The image should hide loading animation with the z-index property.

**Note:** I can't use any javascript solution to hide the loading animation and show it after image load.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.leftprev {
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
    height:99%;
    width:85%;
}
.loadingslide {
    z-index: 50; /* Loading div's z-index */    
}
.spinner.big {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
.spinner {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 60px;
}
.spinner.big > div {
    width: 6px;
}
.spinner > div {
    animation: 1.2s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite stretchdelay;
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
}
a {
    color: #470a09;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slideshow .slidebro .leftprev #slideshowpic {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100; /* image's z-index */    
}
```

```html
<div class="leftprev">
    <div class="loadingslide"> <!-- Loading Animation div (should be running in background of the image) -->
        <div id="tracking" class="spinner big">
            <div class="rect1"></div>
            <div class="rect2"></div>
            <div class="rect3"></div>
            <div class="rect4"></div>
            <div class="rect5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <a id="targetslide" target="_blank" title="Click to view fit to screen" href="">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" alt="" id="slideshowpic" />  <!-- The image (should mask the loading animation div) -->
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` is only used if the element has a position such as `absolute` or `fixed`.  Otherwise, it is ignored and elements are positioned according to the location in the DOM hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add **position** to the element that you want to apply **z-index**.

From CSS-tricks:

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 4):

To position the loading animation correctly:

- Place the loading div inside the container
- Set the container as `position: relative` so that the loading div is positioned in relation to it

To hide the loading animation when the image is loaded:

- The loading div is given `z-index: 1`
- The image is given `position: relative` so that it can have a z-index property
- The image is given `z-index: 2` and will overlap

In this example the image is half the width of the container and you can see how it overlaps the loading div.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #e91e63;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.content img {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
}
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1em;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FF0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="loading">I am loading</div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/250X500" />
</div>
```