# jquery animate slide image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one slider which slide random pictures from a dir.So i want to make animate function which will do margin-top 50px (with that animation picture will be hidden) and after that, new picture will  appear (another function margin-top:0px with new picture). I make that function but i have problem, picture won't to hide, i tried with z-index but wont work...

**HTML**

```
<div class="slika1">
    <img class="img" src="img/1.jpg" id="img" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slika1 {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    min-height:88px;
    max-height:88px;
    min-width:266px;
    max-width:266px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: For proper usage of **z-index** you have to add position to the element: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195972/3834042

Comment: Tried but same story... i want to do like this http://jsfiddle.net/EjZzs/94/

Comment: Can you share your code?